# jQuery: Check Domain & Show Banner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working in a CMS that allows me to share assets across multiple sites.  I've been using a bit of code that allows me to find the domain and show a banner depending on what the domain name is.  And it's worked fine so far.

However, I tried to add an OR in today and it worked, but for some reason, my else (domain3) was adding the wrong class (banner1) in the example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain1.com' || 'www.domain2.com') {
            $('#banner').addClass('banner1');

        } else 

        if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain3.com') {
            $('#banner').addClass('banner2');

        }
    });
```

Could anybody please tell me why?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain1.com' || window.location.hostname == 'www.domain2.com') {
```

Answer (score 1):

change  `if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain1.com' || 'www.domain2.com')`

to

```
 if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain1.com' || window.location.hostname == 'www.domain2.com')
```

This needs to be the case because 'www.domain2.com' will always evaluate to true, thus your else will never get called.